# highcharts inner line on bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a bar chart with both current and previous year values for individual suppliers. On opposite xAxis, I have a margin value. I can explain what I would like better with the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/0m3208qj/2/

What is happening here is that I also have the current and previous values for the Margin. So the line graph has doubled the xAxis. What I would like is, for each xAxis value, there should be a single line with two values. So, lets take column A as an example. I would like :
- a point in A Current year's bar showing the margin for current year
- a point in A Previous year's bar showing the margin for previous year
- a line joining the two
- this line should not continue into the other xAxis series.
- each xAxis should have its own line as above.

I hope I have explained this properly.

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    //zoomType: 'xy',
                    height: 400
                },
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                xAxis: [{ // Suppier names xAxis
                    categories: ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],
                    labels: { rotation: -90 }
                }],
                yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis (Sales)
                    title: {
                        text: '<span class="axis-label">Sales Value (£)</span>',
                        useHTML: true,
                        style: {
                            color: '#89A54E'
                        }
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    }
                , { // Secondary yAxis (Margin %)
                    title: {
                        text: '<span class="axis-label">Margin</span>',
                        useHTML: true
                    },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}%'
                    },
                    opposite: true,
                    min: 0,
                    alignTicks: false,
                    gridLineWidth: 0
                }
                ],
                tooltip: {
                    shared: true
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                credits: { enabled: false },
                plotOptions: {
                    //series: { pointWidth: 25 },
                    //column: {
                    //    pointPadding: 0.5,
                    //    borderWidth: 0
                    //},
                    line: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{y}%',
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                color: '#000000',  
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Current Year',
                    color: '#FFA500',
                    type: 'column',
                    data: [104833.6400,38023.0500,49932.5400,21674.0000,37098.4700,42679.6700,29142.4800,34488.8000,33380.0000,15453.0000],
                    tooltip: {
                        valuePrefix: '£'
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'Previous Year',
                    color: '#5882FA',
                    type: 'column',
                    data: [190233.6800,52147.4200,39609.5700,62502.0000,44805.4400,39057.4800,36631.0000,24868.9000,17111.6800,18819.7000],
                    tooltip: {
                        valuePrefix: '£'
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'Margin',
                    type: 'spline',
                    yAxis: 1,
                    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
                }]
            });
        });
```

EDIT:

Okay - so this example shows what I am trying to do : 
http://jsfiddle.net/0m3208qj/4/.
You can see the line in column B. My problem is that it is showing it in the center, and I would like it in the relevant columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointPlacement) for line serie and move it by setting any number value for this parameter.